# How to prevent unique files in an s3 bucket from being overwritten after a sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to utilize AWS s3 sync to transfer the contents of a local folder to an S3 bucket. I am using the sync command rather than a recursive upload as local can receive new files or changes to existing ones.  However, when a file is not in the local folder, it is removed from the S3 bucket. I believe this is the intended functionality of sync as it believes those files have been removed from local, but for my use case, I would like those files to remain in my S3 bucket even if they were dropped from local. For example:

Before sync:

```
local    remote s3
├── foo  ├── bar
```

After sync:

```
local    remote s3
├── foo  ├── foo
```

For the example above, I am trying to make sure nothing in the S3 bucket is overwritten after a sync between my local and the S3 bucket (it should contain both foo and bar). Is there a way to achieve this functionality by altering the sync command? Furthermore, am I able to achieve this by putting restrictions on the S3 bucket itself to prevent files from being overwritten and make it a write-only bucket?

Comment: [Object locks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/protecting-data-with-amazon-s3-object-lock/) are one way to implement a WORM (Write Once Read Many) storage model in S3. Basically, you can make your bucket objects immutable. I'm not sure what `s3 sync` does in this case... I'm guessing just logs an error.

Comment: No, files in S3 aren't removed during a basic `aws s3 sync` to S3. You need to supply the `--delete` option for that to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [sync — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

> A local file will require uploading if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The local file does not exist under the specified bucket and prefix.
> - The size of the local file is different than the size of the s3 object.
> - The last modified time of the local file is newer than the last modified time of the s3 object.

If any of these criteria are met, then the local file will be uploaded to S3. (The reverse is likely true when doing a sync in the reverse direction.)

If an object already exists in S3 and an object with the same name is uploaded, **the existing object will be overwritten**.

If you wish to retain a copy of that overwritten object, [activate S3 Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html), which will retain previous versions of each object (storage charges apply).

There is also a `--delete` option available for `s3 sync`:

> Files that exist in the destination but not in the source are deleted during sync.

This option will delete files from the **destination location** to match their absence in the source location. The example in your question suggests that you are using this option, since it is the only way that a file will be deleted using the `sync` command.

Answer (score -1):

### Regarding blocking overwritten actions using sync

The sync command aims to keep a destination the same as a source, it recursively **copies new and updated files** from the source directory to the destination.
It won't delete files in the destination which don't exist in the source [by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) until you specify `--delete`. However, it still can't prevent overwriting existing objects in general.

```bash
# any files existing under the specified prefix and bucket but not existing in the local directory will be deleted.
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket --delete
```

The cp command can achieve the same goal as the above. This command with setting `--recursive` will copy all files from your local folder to the S3 bucket without removing any existing files in the bucket.

1. New files will be uploaded
2. **Changes to existing files will be uploaded**

```bash
# example execution
aws s3 cp --recursive /local/folder s3://your-bucket
```

### Regarding blocking overwritten actions via some restrictions

About the overwritten-not-allowed goal, I'm afraid that it cannot be achieved directly by setting S3's attributes.
In [s3 bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-policies.html), you can allow specific identities to put (write) objects only yet the identities **still can overwrite objects** (files).

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPutObjectAndPutObjectAcl",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/your-allowed-role-1",
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/your-allowed-role-2"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Conclusion

You still can design a mechanism which has the overwritten-prevented feature based on natural S3 commands and built-in os commands yet you will have a script to maintain.

#### For Linux and Unix-like

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
local_directory="/path/to/your/local/directory/"
bucket_name="your-bucket-name"

# Function to check and upload a single file
upload_if_not_exists() {
    local_file_path="$1"
    remote_file_path="${local_file_path#${local_directory}}"

    # Check if the remote file exists in the S3 bucket
    if ! aws s3 ls "s3://${bucket_name}/${remote_file_path}" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        aws s3 cp "$local_file_path" "s3://${bucket_name}/${remote_file_path}"
        echo "Uploaded $local_file_path to s3://${bucket_name}/${remote_file_path}"
    else
        echo "Remote file s3://${bucket_name}/${remote_file_path} already exists. Skipping."
    fi
}

# Recursively check and upload files
export -f upload_if_not_exists # Export the function for use with find command
export bucket_name # Export the bucket name variable for use in the function
export local_directory # Export the local directory variable for use in the function
find "$local_directory" -type f -exec bash -c 'upload_if_not_exists "$0"' {} \;
```

#### For Windows

```
$local_directory = "C:\path\to\your\directory"
$bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

Get-ChildItem -Path $local_directory -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $local_file_path = $_.FullName
    $remote_file_path = $_.FullName.Substring($local_directory.Length + 1).Replace('\', '/')
    
    $file_exists = (aws s3 ls "s3://$($bucket_name)/$($remote_file_path)" 2>$null).Length -gt 0

    if (-not $file_exists) {
        Write-Host "Uploading $local_file_path to s3://$($bucket_name)/$($remote_file_path)"
        aws s3 cp "$local_file_path" "s3://$($bucket_name)/$($remote_file_path)"
    }
}
```

Comment: "so based on its essence, it will remove files from the destination that don't exist in the source." Only if you specify the `--delete` flag

Comment: @AnonCoward you are correct. The sync command recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination be default, i.e., it won't delete files in the destination but not the source unless `--delete` is specified.

Comment: @ScottHsieh It will never delete files in the source. It will delete in the destination if `--delete` is used.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks for giving me the note about the `sync` command. :D